# ListView InsertItemTemplate Does not work

Tags: asp.net

I can't get <%# Eval("ID") %> work, although it works outside of the InserItemTemplate.  What is worng?

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" CommandName="InsertPhone" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text="InsertPhone" />

            </td>             
            <td style="width:50px">
                  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPhoneType" DataSourceID='ObjectDataSourcePhoneTypes'
                    DataTextField="Name_ar" DataValueField="ID" />

            </td>
            <td style="width:100px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="PhoneNumberLabel" runat="server" Text='' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert template isn't data bound so you can't use Eval there...  Eval works in the context of a data bound row, but insert row is not data bound, so there's no data source for it.  Programmably set the value in the field if you need to establish some value for a control.

Comment: Agree, you are "Inserting" a record in this mode therefore there is no record for which a field value can be evaluated.  Where do you expect "ID" to be coming from if you haven't created a record yet?